# Producing files in dagster without caring about the filename

Tags: dagster

In the dagster tutorial, in the [Materializiations section](https://dagster.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.0/sections/tutorial/materializations.html), we choose a filename (`sorted_cereals_csv_path`) for our intermediate output, and then yield it as a materialization:

```py
@solid
def sort_by_calories(context, cereals):

    # Sort the data (removed for brevity)

    sorted_cereals_csv_path = os.path.abspath(
        'calories_sorted_{run_id}.csv'.format(run_id=context.run_id)
    )
    with open(sorted_cereals_csv_path, 'w') as fd:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fd, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(sorted_cereals)
    yield Materialization(
        label='sorted_cereals_csv',
        description='Cereals data frame sorted by caloric content',
        metadata_entries=[
            EventMetadataEntry.path(
                sorted_cereals_csv_path, 'sorted_cereals_csv_path'
            )
        ],
    )
    yield Output(None)
```

However, this is relying on the fact that we can use the local filesystem (which may not be true), it will likely get overwritten by later runs (which is not what I want) and it's also forcing us to come up with a filename which will never be used.

What I'd like to do in most of my solids is just say "here is a file object, please store it for me", without concerning myself with *where* it's going to be stored. Can I materialize a file without considering all these things? Should I use python's `tempfile` facility for this?

Answer (score 2):

Actually it seems this is answered in the [output_materialization](https://github.com/dagster-io/dagster/blob/master/examples/dagster_examples/intro_tutorial/output_materialization.py) example.

You basically define a type:

```py
@usable_as_dagster_type(
    name='LessSimpleDataFrame',
    description='A more sophisticated data frame that type checks its structure.',
    input_hydration_config=less_simple_data_frame_input_hydration_config,
    output_materialization_config=less_simple_data_frame_output_materialization_config,
)
class LessSimpleDataFrame(list):
    pass
```

This type has an output_materialization strategy that reads the config:

```
def less_simple_data_frame_output_materialization_config(
    context, config, value
):
    csv_path = os.path.abspath(config['csv']['path'])

    # Save data to this path
```

And you specify this path in the config:

```
    execute_pipeline(
        output_materialization_pipeline,
        {
            'solids': {
                'sort_by_calories': {
                    'outputs': [
                        {'result': {'csv': {'path': 'cereal_out.csv'}}}
                    ],
                }
            }
        },
    )
```

You still have to come up with a filename for each intermediate output, but you can do it in the config, which can differ per-run, instead of defining it in the pipeline itself.